# adding multiple headers in loadRequest?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I want to add multiple headers in my controller.LoadRequest in flutter

```
_controller.loadRequest(
      Uri.dataFromString(fileHtmlContents,mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8')),
      headers: {
        "name":"xxxx",
        "value":"xxxxx",
        "name":"yyyy",//I WANT TO ADD 2 HEADERS İN HERE 
        "value":"yyyy"//  
      }
    );
```

first header gets name and value and second header gets same but it didnt works

please help ı dont know what can ı do

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter#setting-custom-headers-on-post-requests):

> Currently, setting custom headers when making a post request with the
> WebViewController's loadRequest method is not supported on Android. If
> you require this functionality, a workaround is to make the request
> manually, and then load the response data using loadHtmlString
> instead.

I am assuming that this is your use case (you did not provide all of the details).